# Why does "readFile" use more memory than the read file's content length?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I have a path with about 300.000 log files in it.
I noticed memory consumption (leak) when I read all of those files using "readFile" method.

Here is an example of NodeJS code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './parseLogFiles/reports';
var counter = 0;
var totalFileSize = 0;
var fileName;
var fullPath;

function toMb (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

var filesList = fs.readdirSync(path);

console.log('Memory usage before files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

for (var i = 0, len = filesList.length; i < len; i++) {

    fileName = filesList[i];

    if (fileName) {

        fullPath = path + '/' + fileName;

        (function(fullPath){
            fs.stat(fullPath, function(err, stat){
                totalFileSize += stat['size'];
                fs.readFile(fullPath, {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(){
                    if (++counter === len) {
                        console.log('Memory usage after files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
                        console.log('Total files size:', toMb(totalFileSize) + ' MB');
                    }
                });
            });
        })(fullPath);

    }

}
```

I have got the following results:

```
Memory usage before files read: 22.45 MB
Memory usage after files read: 437.80 MB
Total files size: 258.19 MB
```

(437.80 - 22.45 ) / 258.19 = 1.6 (using memory more than read file's content length)

But if I use "readFileSync" method I do not notice memory consumption (leak).

Here is an example of NodeJS code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './parseLogFiles/reports';
var counter = 0;
var totalFileSize = 0;
var fileName;
var fullPath;

function toMb (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

var filesList = fs.readdirSync(path);

console.log('Memory usage before files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

for (var i = 0, len = filesList.length; i < len; i++) {

    fileName = filesList[i];

    if (fileName) {

        fullPath = path + '/' + fileName;

        totalFileSize += fs.statSync(fullPath)['size'];

        try {
            fs.readFileSync(fullPath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        } catch(err){
            console.log('err: ', err);
        }

    }

}

console.log('Memory usage after files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
console.log('Total files size:', toMb(totalFileSize) + ' MB');
```

I have got the following results:

```
Memory usage before files read: 22.45 MB
Memory usage after files read: 23.31 MB
Total files size: 258.19 MB
```

No memory consumption (leak).

Why does it happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "leak"? Is the memory not freed afterwards?

Comment: In your first example you call `process.memoryUsage()` in the complete callback, at this time the data needs to persist in memory, the _overhead_ might be some buffers that where used for reading. In node.js you will - whenever possible - use streams for processing anyway.

Comment: t.niese thanks for your replay. Will it be a good alternative to use "streams" instead of "readFile" method in my situation?

Comment: Juhana thanks for your replay. As I didn't test I bracketed the "leak", to make words "leak" and "consumption" interchangeable.

Comment: Logfiles are a good example where streams fit perfectly. You normally would only need to have one or just a few lines in memory when processing, as of that you would have a stream base line read, passing the log entry to you _log processor_ doing further stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does "readFile" use more memory than the read file's content length?

According to the ECMAscript spec, Javascript strings are represented internally in UTF-16 or UCS-2, both of which require a minimum of to bytes to represent each "character" in the file.  A text file that consists of mostly ASCII characters is likely to roughly double in size when you load it into memory as Javascript strings.

This is orthogonal to the issue of whether or not you have evidence of a memory leak.

(I would say you don't have evidence of a leak.  To demonstrate the existence of a leak you need statics that show the heap size trending upwards over multiple garbage collection cycles.  You are simply reporting a showing a difference in heap usage, before and after loading the files.)

Comment: Stephen C thanks for your reply. I have another question: why "readFile" places file's content into the memory in contrast with "readFileSync" method?

Comment: @Carl - Use the "Ask Question" button.